# Can you do an elasticsearch geo_distance query (or a filter) as a uri request

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to run an elasticsearch query to find items within 10mi of a given point.

I know how to do it with a post, but I would like to use a get with everything in the uri.

I found the below example but it does not work.

```
http://localhost:9200/items/item/_search?{%22query%22:{%22filtered%22:{%22query%22:{%22match_all%22:{}},%22filter%22:{%22geo_distance%22:{%22distance%22:%220.1km%22,%22location%22:{%22lat%22:46.884106,%22lon%22:-71.377042}}}}}}
```

Any way to do this or am I stuck using a post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is the **source=** parameter.  Not to be confused with _source.

```
http://localhost:9200/items/item/_search?source={%22query%22:{%22filtered%22:{%22query%22:{%22match_all%22:{}},%22filter%22:{%22geo_distance%22:{%22distance%22:%220.1km%22,%22location%22:{%22lat%22:46.884106,%22lon%22:-71.377042}}}}}}
```

I had tried ?q= and a few other parameters listed on http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/uri-request/ with no luck (source is not listed).

I found http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/ and at the very bottom it says

> request body in query string
>
> For libraries that don’t accept a request body for non-POST requests,
>   you can pass the request body as the source query string parameter
>   instead.

So structure your query/filter request, set it all on one line and send it into the source parameter.

Do not use the q= parameter with source= or it will conflict and break the query, however I tried size= and from= and they work with source just fine.